# Filtering options best practices for a long list of keyword options

Tags: filter, best-practice

Currently our keyword filter options are ordered by the number of results for each particular keyword. It's a pretty long list and users may not know what options are there but have an idea of what they're looking for. We're going to be hopefully implementing a search, but I'm wondering about the best practice in the event we can't build that. Is it better to order the keywords by number of results or alphabetical (and keep the number of results)? Here is a screenshot of the current keyword filters (the options are more numerous than can be seen currently and require the user to scroll):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this issue in a couple of projects by transforming long list of checkboxes into interactable badges - it saves space because it usually fits 2-3 badges per row, maybe it'll fit your needs as well.

[image]

[Source.](https://medium.com/tripaneer-techblog/improving-the-usability-of-multi-selecting-from-a-long-list-63e1a67aab35)